# Logging in react native app

Tags: react-native, error-logging

What i want is to log my errors and data transfers in my react native app
 i.e the errors which occur during the execution flow should be stored in a file.

What's the best way to do it

Answer (score 0):

React Native ships with a `log-ios` command (and also a `log-android`).

As per the documentation

> You can display the console logs for an iOS or Android app by using the following commands in a terminal while the app is running: (see below snippet)

```
$ react-native log-ios
$ react-native log-android
```

If you want to store this in a file, you could execute

```
$ react-native log-ios > file.txt
```

This will write all logs to, `file.txt`. You will not be able to see the logs as this command is executing so you can open up another terminal window and execute:

```
$ tail -f file.txt
```

This will give you a real time React Native log.

The above commands are written assuming you're on a *nix machine. Windows machines may be slightly different.

Comment: Yeah but this can be done only in case of a debug mode Not in a release build